# When using CAKeyframeAnimation, is it possible not to load all keyframes upfront?

Tags: iphone, optimization, lazy-loading, cakeyframeanimation

I am working on an iOS application where I have some animations that I want to play. For each animation I have all the information in a file(initial position/scale/etc.. and then one keyframe per record in the file).

I am currently using CAKeyframeAnimation as that seemed the most logical choice, however, with some animations where I have a large number of keyframes it's taking ~2s to load all the animations upfront. I would really like to avoid that lag. Furthermore, the animation only really needs 2 keyframes at any point in time and loading all of them at once causes my app to have a very large memory footprint that I'd also like to avoid.

Is it possible to add keyframes on the fly to an already running CAKeyframeAnimation? If so, how?

If it's not possible, what should I use instead of CAKeyframeAnimation?